# Running a Netbeans based compiled C++ program as CGI giving permission error

Tags: c++, mysql, netbeans, cgi, mysql-connector

With the  [help of SO community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411174/mysql-connect-c-64-bit-build-error) I was successful to run my first MySQL based file in C++. Now y next step is to run on Apache as a CGI file. On Apache it's giving 500 Internal Server Error and in server Log I got the following:

```
Sat Jan 19 12:18:18 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jan 19 12:18:23 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jan 19 12:18:23 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Jan 19 12:18:23 2013] [notice] Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.3.2 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 19 12:18:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: addproduct.cgi
```

I performed following steps

1- I went in DEBUG folder generated by netbeans and rename addproduct.o file to addproduct.cgi

2- Copied it in htdocs/myappfolder/

My file is using libs of MySQL and Boost and I guess I am getting error due to same reason. I am willing to know how do I link **includes** and **libs** along with CGI?

The C++ code is given below which comes along with MySQL Connector/C++

**Update:** After fiddling with paths I now get the following error:

> inventory  dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlcppconn.6.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/inventory/Inventory/dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/./inventory
>   Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap http://pastie.org/5723836

**otool** gives the following info:

otool -LMV inventory

```
inventory:
    libmysqlcppconn.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.1)
    time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong file. A .o file is an object file which is the result of compilation but hasn't been linked. I would expect netbeans also has generated a file called addproduct without any extension. That is your executable which can be called by apache.

PS If you are serious about C++ and CGI you might want to have a look at [fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/).

Comment: It's a prototype so I will stick with plain old CGI. I think you're right that I am linking wrong file. But other part of the question, how will it detect included Header and Library files? Since I am not making an Installer so I will to link them up some way.

Comment: running from Command Line: I am getting error * ./inventory 
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlcppconn.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/inventory/Inventory/dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/./inventory
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap*